# Artifactory XRAY failing when scanning images containing golang packages due to indexer compression ratio limits

Tags: docker, go, artifactory, jfrog-xray

Having an issue with XRAY lately when scanning docker images containing golang packages, with the following error snipped

```
TarOpener.DeepArchiveScan) --- Caused by: total bytes limit reached with the following values
```

I've researched the issue, and it is caused by a xray limit on compression ratio for index pacakges, that's in place to prevent zip bomb attacks (https://jfrog.com/help/r/xray-why-am-i-getting-a-total-bytes-limit-reached-error-when-indexing-a-package-in-xray/xray-why-am-i-getting-a-total-bytes-limit-reached-error-when-indexing-a-package-in-xray).

I've been bumping up the limit. That works for a while, but it seems like everytime there is a golang update the size of the compressed file gets larger and larger.

Has anybody implemented a long term fix for this issue or have a novel idea that isn't simply setting the limit to an extreme upper end value?  I've basically been having to nearly double it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang have inserted into their packages the pax-bad-hdr-large.tar.bz2 file which is a test to zip bomb attacks.

a value of 4600 should resolve this file compression ratio.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can create or find a standard golang binary for our team to use that has that test removed, so I don't have to keep the settings for our overall corporate artifactory that high.